# Creating a generic select list generating method of type T

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I was wondering how I might be able to create a re-usable method that creates select lists based on method arguments? I was thinking something like below:

```cs
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CreateSelectList(IList<T> entities, T value, T text)
{

   return  entities
           .Select(x => new SelectListItem
                           {
                               Value = x.value.ToString(),
                               Text = x.text.ToString()
                           });
}
```

I think I have it a bit backwards though. I'm unsure how to call a method like this, when I call it with an IList of Category for the first argument the compiler complains that it cannot assign type Category to type T? Also, how would I insert the method arguments into the lambda? Any help appreciated!

Code I'm trying to use to call it (which is wrong, but you get the idea)

```
viewModel.Categories = _formServices.CreateSelectList(categories, Id, Name);
```

Code I'm trying to make more generic and reusable:

```
viewModel.Categories = categories
                      .Select(x => new SelectListItem
                     {
                         Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                         Text = x.Name
                      });
```

**Edit For Answer**

Credit goes to @Pavel Backshy for working answer. I wanted to edit in an extension I made to his answer in case it helps anybody! The extension just adds a .Where clause into the mix:

```
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CreateSelectListWhere<T>(IList<T> entities, Func<T, bool> whereClause, Func<T, object> funcToGetValue, Func<T, object> funcToGetText)
    {
        return entities
               .Where(whereClause)
               .Select(x => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = funcToGetValue(x).ToString(),
                    Text = funcToGetText(x).ToString()
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define this using Reflection to take property value by name, but I think more elegant and flexible to use Func.
Change your method to:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CreateSelectList<T>(IList<T> entities, Func<T, object> funcToGetValue, Func<T, object> funcToGetText)
{
    return entities
            .Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = funcToGetValue(x).ToString(),
                Text = funcToGetText(x).ToString()
            });
}
```

And then you can use it by this way:

```
viewModel.Categories = _formServices.CreateSelectList(categories, x => x.Id, x => x.Name);
```

Comment: Works a treat, love it. Thanks!

Comment: Good solution. There's missing a type name after `new` (otherwise it'll be an anonymous type and that doesn't fit with the return type). Personally, I would make this a static method.

Comment: This is beautiful indeed! I love the [`Func`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate. They're really powerful.

Answer (score 1):

I found Pavel Bakshy's answer, as well as your edit to include the 'whereClause' very helpful, and exactly what I was trying to accomplish.
Along the same lines I also added a 'selectedValue' object as this was part of what I was trying to do. The 'null' check is for when a list does not have  currently selected value (i.e. when it's first loaded).

Edit: Also I used an IEnumerable instead of IList as my first parameter

```
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ISelectUtils.CreateSelectList<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities, Func<T, bool> whereClause, Func<T, object> funcToGetValue, Func<T, object> funcToGetText, object selectedValue)
    {
        return entities
                .Where(whereClause)
                .Select(x => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = funcToGetValue(x).ToString(),
                    Text = funcToGetText(x).ToString(),
                    Selected =  selectedValue != null ? ((funcToGetValue(x).ToString() == selectedValue.ToString()) ? true : false) : false
                });
    }
```